# No events (connect, message, etc) in the socket.io client

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I see the connection and I see the data in the Chrome console that my frontend got from the server via socket.io library, but there are no JS events in the frontend app. What's wrong with my syntax?

```
this.socket = io(
  'wss://some-url.com',
  {
    path,// URL segment
    transports: [ 'websocket' ],
    reconnection: false
  }
);
this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.info('SocketService->onconnect');
});
this.socket.on('message', (message: string) => {
  console.info('SocketService->onmessage', message);
});
```